# Documentation for theming of unity-greeter

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, lightdm, gtk

There are a lot of great gtk-themes out there for unity/gtk. However very few of them do have support for the unity-greeter. I want to work on them however I were not able to find an (official) documentation on how to do this. I tried to reverse engineer the respective part in `gtk.css` from the Adwaita theme, and I was able to do most of it, but some special widgets I was not able to theme.

Long story short: Is there a documentation somewhere that shows how to theme the unity-greeter?

Just to clarify: I'm talking about this file for example https://github.com/umibps/KABURAGI/blob/master/share/themes/Moe-Pink3/gtk-3.0/apps/unity-greeter.css~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a documentation, but I have found the source code **;)**

```
apt-get source unity-greeter
tar xf unity-greeter_*.tar.xz
cd unity-greeter
```

As the name of the file `gtk.css` says, it's an CSS file with definitions for classes. Let's start a `grep`

```
% grep -r 'add_class' *
Binary file deb/usr/sbin/unity-greeter matches
Binary file dev/usr/sbin/unity-greeter matches
unity-greeter-15.10.1/tests/unity-greeter.vala:        ctx.add_class ("lightdm");
unity-greeter-15.10.1/src/toggle-box.vala:        selected_button.get_style_context ().add_class ("selected");
unity-greeter-15.10.1/src/toggle-box.vala:        item.get_style_context ().add_class ("toggle-button");
unity-greeter-15.10.1/src/unity-greeter.vala:        ctx.add_class ("lightdm");
unity-greeter-15.10.1/src/prompt-box.vala:        option_button.get_style_context ().add_class ("option-button");
unity-greeter-15.10.1/src/prompt-box.vala:        combo.get_style_context ().add_class ("lightdm-combo");
unity-greeter-15.10.1/src/prompt-box.vala:        combo.get_child ().get_style_context ().add_class ("lightdm-combo");
```

or better

```
% grep -rlI 'add_class' * | xargs -I {} awk -F\" '/add_class/ {print $2}' {} | sort -u
lightdm
lightdm-combo
option-button
selected
toggle-button
```

and now we have the supported classes. All other things like `background-image`, `background-color`, `border-color` and so on are CSS definitions.

Dig in the source code and learn [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/). That's the best documentation.

---

**Previous version of my answer, perhaps helpful for further readers**

All you need is in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml`. After editing this file execute:

```
glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Each `key` tag has a `summary` tag to describe what the key does. Some examples:

1. The background image

   ```
   <key name="background" type="s">
     <default>'/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'</default>
     <summary>Background file to use, either an image path or a color (e.g. #772953)</summary>
   </key>
   ```

   - `type="s"` means, wee need a string for the tag `default`
   - The value is an absolute path to an image file
2. The background color

   ```
   <key name="background-color" type="s">
     <default>'#2C001E'</default>
     <summary>Background color (e.g. #772953), set before wallpaper is seen</summary>
   </key>
   ```

   - `type="s"` means, wee need a string for the tag `default`
   - The value is a color code
3. Show the hostname

   ```
   <key name="show-hostname" type="b">
     <default>true</default>
     <summary>Whether to show the hostname in the menubar</summary>
   </key>
   ```

   - `type="b"` means, wee need a boolean value for the tag `default`
   - Valid values: true/false
4. The resolution settings

   ```
   <key name="xft-dpi" type="d">
     <default>96</default>
     <summary>Resolution for Xft in dots per inch</summary>
   </key>
   ```

   - `type="d"` means, wee need numerical value for the tag `default`
   - Use `xrdb -query | grep dpi` to determine a correct value or play with the value to see the behavior

<sub>[partially source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#Unity_greeter)</sub>

Trial and error and reading the source code is the best documentation **=)**

Comment: Very usefull thanks, but that's actually not exactly what I am looking for (all the settings you showed above are accesible using dconf-editor as well) What I want to understand is how [this] (https://github.com/umibps/KABURAGI/blob/master/share/themes/Moe-Pink3/gtk-3.0/apps/unity-greeter.css~) file for example is working

Comment: I don't agree with your verdict :) "Trial and error is the best documentation =)". Not the best way of solving problems according to me :)

Comment: @kisanme Ok, you're right. But the source code is a great documentation :)

Comment: @A.B. indeed the source code is :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation for Unity Greeter theming. The Adwaita CSS and Unity Greeter source are your best places to look at what can be themed.